# Liquid State Machine: How is it different to Spiking Neural Network Models

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks

I am very new to the 'reservoir computing world', and I've heard that the Liquid State Machines (LSM) are a certain kind of spiking neuron network models (SNN). Exactly what is the difference in terms of the implementation between the two.

Another aspect on which I need some clarity is in regards to their counterpart the 'Leaky integrator models of Echo state network (ESN). I found from another answer in the forum that 'as I see it (I could be wrong) the big difference between the two approaches is the individual unit. In liquid state machine use biological like neurons, and in the Echo state use more analog units. So in term of “very short term memory” the Liquid State approach each individual neuron remember its own history, where in the Echo state approach each individual neuron react base only on the current state, there for the memory stored in the activity between the units.

Please tell me if this is the correct and if not what is the actual concept behind them.